# Observer is calling multiple times

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios9, observers

I am adding observer in viewdidload -

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:aName object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(aMethod) name:aName object:nil];
```

But every time when i am opening view its adding observer. How to manage this?

Comment: If you add an observer in `viewDidLoad` you should remove the observer in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: don't know dealloc is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:aName object:nil];

   }

  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(aMethod) name:aName object:nil];
}
```

Comment: `viewWillDisappear` is not the right place to remove your observers if you are adding them in `viewDidLoad`. View might disappear several times without loading the view again which will try to remove a non-existant observer resulting into a crash.

Comment: This answer assumes the notification should only be processed while the view controller is in view. That may not be appropriate depending on the needs of the view controller.

Comment: if the needs are more specific , the answer will be modified